# Why am I getting Black Cells in when using longtables?

Tags: longtable, colortbl

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs, colortbl}

\title{test}
\author{xyz}
\date{May 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{longtable}{p{7cm}p{7cm}}
    \caption{V Lorem ipsum\cite{24bidgoli2014handbook}\cite{25tipton2008information}\cite{13MITRE_ATTACK_Framework}\cite{26ghernoutiSecurityStrategy}}
    \label{tab: Lorem ipsum}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor[gray]{0.8}
        \toprule
            \textbf{ Lorem ipsum} & \textbf{Lorem ipsum} \\ [0.5ex]
            \hline
            \midrule
            Lorem ipsum &  Lorem ipsum 
            \\ \hline
             Lorem ipsum &  Lorem ipsum
            \\ \hline
            Lorem ipsum &  Lorem ipsum
            \\ \hline
             Lorem ipsum &  Lorem ipsum
            \\ \hline
        \bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

This results in this:
[image: Result of code]

I am not sure how to get rid of this. I expect it to be some package collision with long tables but I am not sure. Anyone dealt with this before?

Comment: Delete `\hline\rowcolor[gray]{0.8}` and your problem should vanish.

Comment: why did you tag this biblatex?

Comment: Thank you that solved it!